# resourceIdMatches() doesn't work in Appium UiSelector

Tags: java, android, regex, uiscrollview, appium

I'm using appium for Android.

Take a look at the screenshot attached. I have 3 RecyclerView classes, each of them has its own ID.

I want to scroll the second RecyclerView which has the ID `timePickerRecyclerMinutes` until I find the value I require. I have the following query, but it does not work:

```
String query = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\"*:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"50\"))";
```

The error is:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1 *:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes^
```

I also tried the ID `resourceIdMatches(\"timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")` - did not help. I understand that there is some regex error, can you point me out how to fix it?

When I use full ID and `resourceId()`, it works:

```
resourceId(\"com.dstarlab.icommunicator.internal:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")
```

[image]

Comment: try with escaping as `\"*:id\/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\"`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Did not help.

Comment: most likely the issue is with the escaping as you are sending it as string query, can try `\\/` or maybe `\\\"` `\\/` for slashes and double quotes

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Still nothing

Comment: @LexSav  You don’t need to mention any regex or full resource id. Just give part after ‘:id/‘ means “timePickerRecyclerMinutes” should work in your case.

Comment: @Muzzamil As I already wrote, "I also tried the ID resourceIdMatches(\"timePickerRecyclerMinutes\") - did not help".

Comment: okay but why you have used \"timePickerRecyclerMinutes\" instead "timePickerRecyclerMinutes"

Comment: @Muzzamil It's a specific of the UISelector query. The ID or class needs to be enwrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @LexSav Can you please try this resourceIdMatches(\".*:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")

Comment: @Muzzamil Sorry for the late answer. Yes, you were right. I just had to put a dot in the beginning.
Add this as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Okay perfect I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dot. So you have to change

**From**

```
String query = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\"*:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"50\"))";
```

**To**

```
String query = "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\".*:id/timePickerRecyclerMinutes\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"50\"))";
```